# installing ghostscript with vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ghostscript

I would like to install ghostscript when creating my vagrant environment but i have no idea how to achieve this. My provisioning script looks as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y wget php5 apache2

# Apache stuff
sudo a2enmod rewrite

rm -rf /var/www

ln -fs /vagrant /var/www

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your shell provisioning script you must define the following commands

```
wget http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostscript-9.10.tar.bz2

tar xjf ghostscript-9.10.tar.bz2 

cd ghostscript-9.10

rm -rf zlib && ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-compile-inits \ --enable-dynamic --with-system-libtiff && make

make so

su root

make install

gs -v
```

What this basically does is:

1. download the package
2. extract the contents
3. compiles ghostscript
4. installs ghostscript
5. checks if it installed correctly

Above explanation has to send you on it's way to install it